# How to determine where a mouse exits an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

On this page: http://www.colorz.fr/#!/work/

You can see the image scrolls into/out of the direction where the mouse enters and leaves. How is this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the x/y coordinates of the cursor when the `mouseleave` event fires for the element:

```
$('#my-element').on('mouseleave', function (event) {

    //check to see what quadrant of the element the mouse has left the element
    //you could get a lot more complex than this but here's an example to get you going
    if (event.offsetX > 50 && event.offsetY > 50) {
        alert('bottom-right');
    } else if (event.offsetX > 50 && event.offsetY <= 50) {
        alert('top-right');
    } else if (event.offsetX <= 50 && event.offsetY <= 50) {
        alert('top-left');
    } else {
        alert('bottom-left');
    }
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bKVwR/1/

Answer (score 0):

Due to the `mouseout` event and the `screenX`/`screenY`/`clientX`/`clientY` properties it is possible to calculate the direction with simple trigonomics.

Answer (score 0):

It's only responding to vertical and horizontal directions. If you try diagonal pictures, it doesn't work.
So based on that, I think you can use `mousemove` event to give you x and y displacements. If x displace is larger than y, that means user is moving horizontally and vice-versa.